# Will Swift do some performance optimization using filter, map, reduce rather than using for loop?

Tags: swift

Will Swift do some performance optimization using filter, map, reduce rather than using for loop? Maybe in the multithread or compiler optimization level, there will be some elegant advantages? I don't know it, and does anybody know this? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Map.swift

Answer (score 0):

Yes. by using `@autoclosure` for preventing extra calculation, `reservedCapacity` to boost allocation performance, `Index` instead of `count` to preventing unnecessary loops and etc. You can use them yourself in your own implementation. But as you may already know, performance optimization of a list is depend on the many things like the type of the values, count of them, and etc. Swift has a great performance optimization for general purpose usages but maybe those are not the **BEST Case** for your specific usage.